# Network Sharing Issues

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I have two computers I want to have on a network share together (so the laptop can print through the desktop's printer).

These are both connected to the same router. (One wired and one wireless) And they both have the same workgroup name.

However, when I type "net view" in the command prompt, the only computer that shows up is the computer I type the command into.

How do I get these computers to be shared with each other?

**Update**: The tower is running Windows XP, the Laptop is running Windows 7. I have disabled the Firewall on both until I get this set up.

**Update 2:** Typing the command net view on my desktop is acting very strangely. Noe sometimes it only shows itself on the list of computers, sometimes it shows itself and the laptop and sometimes it doesn't work at all and displays system error 6118.

I typed net view into the command prompt on the Windows 7 laptop and both computers showed up, so I went to connect to the desktop from the laptop and it said the dekptop could not be found, even though it is showing up int he list of shared computers.

Here are supporting pictures (these are coming from the laptop)

[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide more information like OS-Version, installed Firewalls...

Comment: Perhaps provide an `ipconfig` from both computers, or (better) just provide pertinent IP setting information. Can they ping each other?

Comment: Yes, they can ping each other. The Desktop's local IP is 192.168.1.107 and the laptop is 192.168.1.101

Comment: Make sure the laptop has the network set as a Work or Home network, and not as Public.